# Designing models in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

I am having very hard times choosing a definite way to create models in Angular. For several weeks, I've been doing things like this:

```
documentModule.factory('Document',function(){

    function MyModel(){
        this.prop = ''
    }

    MyModel.prototype.foobar = function(){
        // Some logic to perform on model data
    };

    return{
        getInstance: function(){
            return new MyModel();
        }
    }

});
```

I add all methods that are working with model data to the prototype.

I recently had the pleasure to read a free ebook on "Human JavaScript" which you may have already stumbled upon: http://read.humanjavascript.com

In chapter 7, 'Models', they introduce a way of providing the model to the application that has imposed on me. I like the idea of "being able to open the code for the model and read what properties it stores and what types those properties have"

However, I am not a too smart man myself and can't come up with a solution to use this with Angular. Also, how are you working with models?

**What are your thoughts about this concept and would you recommend to implement something similiar with Angular? If so, how would you begin?**

Comment: This is not the correct way to create your model. please let me know what do you want to do? help can be done...

Comment: Well, one could say that I'm simply looking for that * **one, correct way** *

Comment: I've been working with Angular for some time now. I just can't decide *how* to provide a model.

Comment: okay. misunderstood by me.

Answer (score 1):

I do think that it is a good idea to use the prototype inheritance, it provides a proper place for certain logic which can help to keep controllers lean.

I would propose a simplfication for your example:

```
documentModule.factory('MyModel',function(){

  function MyModel(){
      this.prop = ''
  }

  MyModel.prototype.foobar = function(){
      // Some logic to perform on model data
  };

  return MyModel;
});
```

An use MyModel like so:

```
documentModule.factory('MyModelController',function($scope, MyModel){
  $scope.myModel = new MyModel();
});
```

Take a look at $resource https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource if you'd like to have basic REST-support for your models.

Comment: How would you provide default values?

Comment: I'd say that the statement this.prop = '' i effectively defining the empty string as the default value of 'prop'. Be cautious about over engineering your models - with angular, plain old javascript objects works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

There is one different – models in `Human JavaScripts` are not constructors – you can’t pass arguments on instantiate process.

To provide default values just modify `defaults` object inside factory

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .factory('model', function () {function model(args) {
        var defaults = {
            foo: 'default value',
            bar: 'default value',
            quux: 'other value'
        };

        this.options = angular.extend(defaults, args);
    }

    model.prototype.getAccessToOptions = function () {
        return this.options;
    };

    return model;
})
    .controller('model', function ($scope, model) {
    var model = new model({
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar'
    });

    console.log('model.getAccessToOptions()', model.getAccessToOptions());
    // model.getAccessToOptions() Object {foo: "foo", bar: "bar", quux: "other value"} 
});
```